# Problem with <!--[if !IE]> on a windows server

Tags: internet-explorer, browser, google-chrome

I know is not the best solution, but I need to make a little difference in how to open links in ie and the rest of browser because of a problem with the shockwave plugin.

I'm on a windows server working with asp (I preffer php, but I need to work with this for a particular project)

```
<!--[if IE ]> <a href="#" title="Game" onclick="abrir('http://www.link.com/',0,0,0,0,0,0,0,700,400,100,100,1);"> <!--<![endif]-->
<!--[if !IE ]> <a class='example5' href="http://www.link.com" title="Game"> <!--<![endif]-->
<img src="img/game.png" style="border:0px"  alt="Single Player" /></a>
```

This is working for ie, but not working for chrome

on ie the link is working, on chrome not =(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comments are handled client side, so the server is irrelevant.

Your syntax is wrong for the non-IE comment. Since only IE treats conditional comments in a special way, you can't have an end result that looks like a regular comment if you want non-IE browsers to treat it as content.

See [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#dlrevealed). Trying to figure out the syntax using logic doesn't work, as it isn't a language feature but a hack.

```
<![if !IE]>
<link href="non-ie.css" rel="stylesheet">
<![endif]>
```

Comment: Great, thanks, I love stack =) I will give you point when allowed by minimum time =)